# Как функции OpenSSL работают с памятью?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, openssl, утечка-памяти

На официальном wiki openssl есть [пример](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Signing_and_Verifying) функции создания цифровой подписи (Calculating HMAC).

1. При первом вызове функции выделяется память, но не освобождается (снимок 3).
2. При повторном вызове функции память уже не выделяется (снимок 4).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Функция подписи из примера:

```
int hmac_it(const unsigned char* msg, size_t mlen, unsigned char** val, size_t* vlen, EVP_PKEY* pkey)
{
    /* Returned to caller */
    int result = 0;
    EVP_MD_CTX* ctx = NULL;
    size_t req = 0;
    int rc;

    if (!msg || !mlen || !val || !pkey)
        return 0;

    *val = NULL;
    *vlen = 0;

    ctx = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
    if (ctx == NULL) {
        printf("EVP_MD_CTX_create failed, error 0x%lx\n", ERR_get_error());
        goto err;
    }

    rc = EVP_DigestSignInit(ctx, NULL, EVP_sha256(), NULL, pkey);
    if (rc != 1) {
        printf("EVP_DigestSignInit failed, error 0x%lx\n", ERR_get_error());
        goto err;
    }

    rc = EVP_DigestSignUpdate(ctx, msg, mlen);
    if (rc != 1) {
        printf("EVP_DigestSignUpdate failed, error 0x%lx\n", ERR_get_error());
        goto err;
    }

    rc = EVP_DigestSignFinal(ctx, NULL, &req);
    if (rc != 1) {
        printf("EVP_DigestSignFinal failed (1), error 0x%lx\n", ERR_get_error());
        goto err;
    }

    //*val = OPENSSL_malloc(req);
    *val = (unsigned char*)OPENSSL_malloc(req);
    if (*val == NULL) {
        printf("OPENSSL_malloc failed, error 0x%lx\n", ERR_get_error());
        goto err;
    }

    *vlen = req;
    rc = EVP_DigestSignFinal(ctx, *val, vlen);
    if (rc != 1) {
        printf("EVP_DigestSignFinal failed (3), return code %d, error 0x%lx\n", rc, ERR_get_error());
        goto err;
    }

    result = 1;


err:
    EVP_MD_CTX_free(ctx);
    if (!result) {
        OPENSSL_free(*val);
        *val = NULL;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Вызов функции 2 раза подряд:

```
EVP_PKEY* pKey = nullptr;
...
// Создаем pKey
...
unsigned char* signData = nullptr;
size_t signedDataLen = 0;

std::string msg1 = "message 1";
std::string msg2 = "message 2";

// СНИМОК 2 (Состояние до первого вызова функции)
// Первый вызов    
hmac_it((const unsigned char*)msg1.data(), msg1.length(), &signData, &signedDataLen, pKey);

OPENSSL_free(signData);

// СНИМОК 3
// Второй вызов
hmac_it((const unsigned char*)msg2.data(), msg2.length(), &signData, &signedDataLen, pKey);

OPENSSL_free(signData);

// СНИМОК 4 (Состояние после второго вызова функции)
```

Почему между 3им и 2ым снимками память выделяется, а между 3им и 4ым нет. Я же вызываю одну и ту же функцию?

Comment: ¿а там не показывается, на что ушла память?

Comment: @user7860670 да. Внутри библиотеки происходит выделение памяти. Вопрос, как ее правильно освободить?

Comment: Хм, это странно, должно показываться по идее.